# Como acessar uma página do servidor NGINX de uma instancia ubuntu do AWS através da internet?

Tags: amazon-aws

Acabei de criar uma instância do ubuntu no AWS e instalei o NGINX como servidor.
Parece que tudo está correto:

```
root@ip-172-31-8-234:/home/ubuntu# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11856/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1328/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11856/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1328/sshd
```

E essa é a página inicial do servidor NGINX:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-234:~$ curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou acessando através d SSH - putty.

Quando eu tento acessar pelo browser, na internet recebo um erro:

```
This site can’t be reached

54.94.152.233 took too long to respond.
```

Essas são as configurações da instância na AWS:

```
Public DNS (IPv4) - ec2-54-94-152-233.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Instance state - running
IPv4 Public IP - 54.94.152.233
```

Eu não estou conseguindo acessar a página welcome do NGINX pela internet. O que estou fazendo de errado? Tem alguma configuração faltando no AWS?

Comment: Uma pergunta: você liberou a porta 80 no inbound da security group da instância? Ela vem por default não acessível.

Comment: deu certo. Publica sua resposta.

Comment: publiquei a resposta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve liberar a porta 80 no `Security Group` da Instância, que, por padrão, vem inacessível.

Na aba `Inbound`, só adicionar a regra correspondente: se colocar `HTTP` no `Type`, ele já preenche o campo com a porta 80.

Source `0.0.0.0` abre para todos. Ou você pode preencher seu IP para somente você acessar (existe um *helper* ali `My IP` que preenche com seu IP).